# SCNNode Pivot Location

Tags: swift, rotation, pivot, scenekit, scnnode

Let's say I have 2 `SCNNodes` node1 and node2.

I want node1 to have a position of `node1.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)`

I want node2 to have a position of `node2.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 1)`

Now, I want node2 to have rotate around node1. Therefore, I attempt to do, `node2.pivot = self.phone.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, -1)`.

This provides the it where it rotates around node1 such that if I rotate node2 by Pi/2, then it is on top of the node, i.e., if I rotate `node1.rotate(Double.pi/2, 0, 0)` it actually is on top of node1.

How can I get it where ndoe2 pivots around node1?

**Edit1:**

```
self.container = SCNNode()
self.container.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)

self.node2 = SCNNode(geometry: geom2)
self.node2.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 1)
self.container.addChildNode(self.node2)

let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: self.node2)
constraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = false

self.node1 = SCNNode(geometry: geom)
self.node1.position = SCNVector(0, 0, 0)
self.node1.constraints = [constraint]
```

Node1 never moves, as node2 never moves. I.e., node2 will ALWAYS be at position `(0, 0, 1)` since the container is the only thing rotating.

Comment: I just tested this in a playground and, as expected, node1 __does__ rotate together with node2

Comment: Hell, i’ll try it again lol.

Comment: It is impossible that yours works... `node2` never moves as it is always at position. I am in a playground, and as expected, as I rotate `node2` will rotate, however, `node1` does not move. `node2` is stuck at position `(0, 0, 1)` and never actually moves. Therefore, `node1` never rotates.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with `pivot` elements at all make use of the node hierachy.

Something like this should work

```
- node1
|
| - rotation center
  | - node 2
```

Then rotate the rotation center, not node 2 directly. Since a node always rotates around it's coordinate center and a node's coordinate space is always relative to it's parent this works just fine.

Comment: While I normally agree, I am trying to have a 3rd node, `look(at:)` the other node. If I just rotate a central node `node1` in your case, `node2` never actually moves, therefore, how do I get it to `look(at:)`?

Comment: `node2` does move and a `SCNLookAtConstraint` should work just fine.

Comment: I can't use SCNLookAtConstraint as I need to alter the axes as they rotate in a specific manner. I.e., best option right now is to create a pivot